# Why are "devices utilized exclusively in any transportation vehicle" exempted from FCC compliance testing?

Tags: automotive, emc, fcc

I was researching whether do we need to do FCC compliance testing for a device we developed for a client. Curiously, it seems to be in the list of exemptions (passage taken from [here](https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/398)):

> A digital device utilized exclusively in any transportation vehicle including motor vehicles and aircraft.

This got me wondering why such an exemption is there in the first place? Aren't badly-designed intentional radiators just as bad when mounted on a car?

My guess would be that in the past, motor vehicles used ignition systems which are known to cause interference, so EMI-wise, the situation is bad enough already. But it certainly strikes me as odd if that rationale lives on in the 21<sup>st</sup> century!

Could somebody shed light? (I'm mostly just curious, but the rationale behind this exemption might be of importance to us).

Comment: Another reason to not end up in an ambulance

Comment: Automotive giants corrected their high ignition noise with 50k Ohm carbon ignition wires to replace copper ones decades ago. The power industry always has a responsibility to track down arc noise interference upon complaints or during routine maintenance. Now the FCC has collected over $750k in negotiated settlements in a recent campaign to eliminate LED sign industry unintended emissions.  I wonder if self-driving cars that may use Radar are compliant.

Comment: here is a link to the actual  document .... https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/CFR-2010-title47-vol1/pdf/CFR-2010-title47-vol1-sec15-103.pdf ...... it basically says `we won't test your device, but we will certainly tell you to stop using it if there is harmful interference` ...... it is in the manufacturer's best self interest to limit the interference emission at the design stage

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I just read that intentional radiators always require certification and are not under that vehicle exemption.

Comment: @jsotola Perhaps, but remember there are things such as unpowered sailplanes which won't need that type of shielding to protect it from itself.

Answer (score 1):

Car and aircraft manufacturers have [extensive industry standards](http://www.ets-lindgren.com/sites/etsauthor/WhitePapers/ICM_Feb16_Dabreu-Fanning-Sarwar.pdf) and company specifications for EMC/EMI. For cars these standards include CISPR 25 and SAE J1113. Aircraft have RTCA DO-160 and MIL-STD-461. These are in many ways much stricter than FCC Part 15 and are required for safety certifications, such as by the FAA or the European Community Whole Vehicle Type Approval (ECWVTA) process.

The issue is that vehicles are safety critical. As one engineer who works in the field told me, people will drive up to broadcast towers. You cannot have the engine computer sensors misread and cause the engine to explode. As a result, they drive cars into [anechoic chambers](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1428190) and use kilowatt transmitters to test them. Likewise airplanes get struck by lightning on a regular basis and must continue to operate normally.

Typically, if you shield your systems against this energy going in, you will prevent radiation at the same time. On the other hand, consumer devices rarely have legislated immunity requirements, everybody remembers speakers picking up TDMA cell phones.

Car manufacturers will even have standards on how good their radio should work, for customer satisfaction. One of the issues I heard about was that Qi wireless charging pads have the potential to interfere with AM reception, which is why they're often stuck deep in the console.

In sum, the vehicle industry has adequate self-regulation for safety, so the FCC doesn't need to worry.

Comment: Yeah, but those specs don't explain why you can plug a device into a home and it has to be FCC certified as an unintentional radiator, but in a vehicle it doesn't. The FCC gives you a 'free pass' of sorts if it goes into a vehicle.

Comment: @laptop2d Read the very last sentence of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, intentional radiators do not fall under that vehicle exemption. Intentional radiators always require certification.

The reason the unimportant stuff is not exempted is so the unimportant stuff won't interfere with the important stuff (which is exempted). Peoples' lives might depend on the equipment in transportation vehicles (especially airplanes) so it's exempted because it gets top priority and everything unimportant is supposed to accommodate and acquiesce to it. The unexempted stuff is most important so gets the least restrictions so it is able to do whatever is needed to get the job done. I think some hospital equipment *might* fall under something similar.

It's a bit like saying "civilians must stay 10 feet from the king at all times" giving the king priority and right-of-way, and then asking how come the king doesn't have the same rule as the civilians? The answer is the king wouldn't have similar rules because the rule exists to give the king priority in the first place.

Also, my understanding is that the the FCC tests only involve MEASURING emissions from a device. They do not bombard a device with EMI and observe if the devices still work properly which is why they do not certify the "important" stuff. The manufacturer might care, but the FCC doesn't. The FCC's only objective is to keep the airwaves organized and clean so it doesn't hinder the important stuff.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Even if you go with the "importance" theory, surely it's important to ensure that electronic equipment in a vehicle isn't subject to excessive EMI from other equipment?

Comment: The expectation is that everything in the vehicle is designed to work with itself. That is all under control of the manufacturer. And the fact that the vehicle is not subjected to excessive EMI from other "unimportant" equipment is already taken into account by requiring that other unimportant equipment be certified. Remember that the FCC compliance testing checks that the emissions remain below a certain level (to not mess with the exempted important stuff), and require the device to accept any and all interference.

Comment: Are you assuming the FCC bombards devices under test to ensure they still work properly? Because I don't think that's the case. The manufacturer of the device might care, but I don't think the FCC does. If you know of a test, that would dampen my argument but I've never heard of one.

Comment: Also, intentional radiators do NOT fall under that exemption. Intentional radiators always require FCC certification.

Comment: I agree on FCC egress but it also includes ingress except it only applies to the devices.  I just checked my Mercedes SUV users manual.  USA: "The wireless devices of this vehicle comply with Part 15 of the FCC Rules....These devices may not cause harmful interference, and 2) These devices must accept any interference received, including interference that may cause undesired operation... Changes
or modifications not expressly approved by the
party responsible for compliance could void the
user’s authority to operate the equipment."  (I new a guy who could design a police radar blaster)

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 That makes sense I think. I said that I read intentional radiators were not under the exemption but the wording seems to indicate that "wireless devices" in general, which intentional radiators falls under, are do not fall under the exemption.

Comment: The clarification about intentional radiators is a very welcome one. I have a question though: our devices contain one module (call it "A"), which is an intentional radiator, and "B" which is unintentional  (optional power adapter). B should be exempt, but since it's expected to be used in conjunction with A, what shall we send for testing? {A}, or {A, A+B}, or {A+B}?

Answer (score -1):

The FCC certifications are there to stop radio interference. One way this can happen is through unintentional radiators.

If you have an unintentional radiator, it needs to be tested for conducted emissions and for unintentional emissions.

My guess is if a device is only being used in a car/airplane, conducted emissions are much less of a problem (with the exception of interference to your car radio, but that would be apparent because you'd be able to locate the offending device quickly, in a house not so much). Conducted emissions wouldn't flow down AC mains to a neighbors house and cause problems, just be localized to the vehicle. Even unintentional emissions are *less* of a problem since the device is in a metal box in the case of both cars and planes.

Comment: Also, the electrical system of automobiles is notoriously noisy and terrible, which might play into it somehow.

Comment: If this was true, they'd exempt battery-powered devices, but they don't. Battery powered devices are only exempt from the conducted emissions portion.

Comment: Battery devices aren't in a "Faraday cage"